# $O(\log n)$ search algorithm for a sorted natural number array with block of 0s on right

Tags: algorithms, search

Assume A is an m sized array containing n ($m \ge n$) natural numbers (excluding $0$), sorted on the left of it.
All remaining cells on right are filled with zeros.

For example, $m=10, n=4$:

$$A = \{5,7,11,24,0,0,0,0,0,0\}$$

How can I find the index of a natural number x in A with $O(\log \boldsymbol{n})$ complexity?

**Edit:** $n$ is not known.

Comment: Can you solve the same problem if there are no zeros at the end? That is, can you find a given number in a sorted array with $O(\log(n))$ complexity?

Comment: Sorry, should have made it clear that n is not known. If it were, simple binary search would work.

Comment: Actually your case also can be solved using binary search. Do you have any ideas how it should be modified?

Comment: I thought of finding a rough estimate of where the zeros start by going through the array and checking if I found a zero already. I do this by checking cell index 1,2,4,8,16 etc. This way I stay within O(logn)

Answer (score 2):

A two-stage binary search works. First, for the purposes of this search define $0$ to be greater than any positive integer.

Then, let $l = 1$ and $h = 2$ and:

1. While $A_h \leq x$ let $l \leftarrow h$ and $h \leftarrow 2h$. Since for all $h > n$ we have $A_h = 0$, which we defined to be greater than any positive number, this loop must exit within $O(\log n)$ iterations.
2. Now $A_l \leq x < A_h$, and $A$ is sorted, so we can do a binary search in range $[l, h]$. This also takes $O(\log n)$ steps since $l,h \leq 2n$.

Comment: You can even eliminate one of the steps. It is enough to run a simple binary search and to take a left subsegment of current segment each time the middle of a current segment points to zero.

Comment: @VladislavBezhentsev That has the wrong complexity if $|A| \gg n$, and impossible when $|A|$ is not known.

Comment: Oh indeed, seems that I misread a required complexity. My bad.

Comment: You need a bit more hand-waving without $n$ having been specified not to exceed $m/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Take a modified "compare" operation which considers 0 to be larger than any other number. Then use ordinary binary search. That's all.

Missed the "O(log m)" requirement... Easy. You check the elements at index 2^20, 2^400,2^8,000, 2^160,000 etc. first. Except for m = 1, log n is at most 20 times larger than log m. As long as you realise that the "block of zeroes" at the right side is a red herring.

Comment: That binary search would take log(m) steps in the worst-case. The question is asking for O(log(n)) operations.

Comment: `the "block of zeroes" at the right side is a red herring` to divert your attention from finding something in the first $m$ positions without disclosing $m$ reads a legitimate interpretation.